# Count which cycle of the alphabet this letter is in [python]

Tags: python

I have this alphabetic cycle `A B C D` which represent the phase an item is in. An item can cycle through the phase more than once, so I need to find out if an item is in its first phase A, or its second phase A.

Letters can be missing which makes this a bit tricky. See correct outputs:

```
test_1 = ['A','B','C','D','A','B']
output_1 = [1,1,1,1,2,2]

test_2 = ['A','B','D','A','B','C']
output_2 = [1,1,1,2,2,2]

test_3 = ['B','A','B','C']
output_3 = [1,2,2,2]
```

Note that in `test_2` we accurately note the first occurrence of phase C is in the *2nd* cycle.

My attempts are below:

```
import itertools

test_1 = ['A','B','C','D','A','B']
output_1 = [1,1,1,1,2,2]

test_2 = ['A','B','D','A','B','C']
output_2 = [1,1,1,2,2,2]

test_3 = ['B','A','B','C']
output_3 = [1,2,2,2]

valid_phase_seq=['A','B','C','D']


def count_phases(phase_list):
    '''
    We will see whether this is the 1st phase A, or the 2nd phase A.
    :param phase_list:
    :return: int list
    '''
    phase_counts = []
    valid_iter = itertools.cycle(valid_phase_seq)
    count = 1

    # failed approach #2
    while len(phase_counts) != len(phase_list):
        for valid_phase in valid_iter:
            for curr_phase in phase_list:
                if valid_phase == curr_phase:
                    phase_counts.append(count)
            count += 1

    # failed approach #1
    # for curr_phase in phase_list:
    #     # Look at a phase
    #     curr_valid = next(valid_iter)
    #
    #     # We are in another cycle
    #     if curr_valid == 'A' and len(phase_counts) > 1:
    #         count += 1
    #         valid_iter = itertools.cycle(valid_phase_seq)
    #         curr_valid = next(valid_iter)
    #
    #     # We are in the same cycle
    #     #if curr_phase == curr_valid:
    #     phase_counts.append(count)

    return phase_counts
```

Comment: Is the question any more complicated than "how many times has this letter appeared before?" ?

Comment: Note that in test_2 we accurately note the first occurrence of phase C is in the 2nd cycle.

Comment: What exactly is the rule that tells you when a new cycle has started? For example, suppose I have `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`. How do I know this doesn't actually represent *two* cycles, where `'C' and `'D'` are missing from the first cycle, and `'A'` and `'B'` are missing from the second cycle?

Comment: Any instance in `A B C D` that is not sequentially previous. C D is the same cycle. C C is two cycles.

Comment: What should the output be for `['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C']`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice 1 1 1 2 2

Comment: I think I understand. As long as the letters are in alphabetic order, they are part of the same cycle, and then the next letter that *doesn't* follow that rule, must start a new cycle?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to cycle through the valid phases is overthinking it. Just cycle through the actual data:

```
def number_cycles(phases):
    cycles = []
    current_cycle, previous_phase = 1, None
    for current_phase in phases:
        if previous_phase is not None and previous_phase >= current_phase:
            current_cycle += 1
        previous_phase = current_phase # for next loop
        cycles.append(current_cycle)
    return cycles
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It's perfect.

Also re: your earlier comment about how we know if A and B are the same phase with and C and D; with this particular data, unfortunately, we don't, we are just assuming they are.

Comment: Well, with the assumption, we have a solvable problem at least :)

Comment: I'm comparing letters in the `_phase` variables that come from the input sequence. I suppose, for example `'@'` would work, or anything lexicographically before `'A'`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have too many loops. In psuedocode, I would do something like this:

```
for letter in phase_list
    if letter starts a new phase
        count += 1
    phase_counts.append(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Karl beat me to it with a super simple solution. I on the other hand got it a little more complicated but will post anyway as I already put the time to it...

My idea was to use a cyclic counter with a mapping between each letter to an index. This way we loop on the letters and add one to each index up to that letter, cyclicly. Goes something like:

```py
from itertools import count

def phase_count(phases):
    letters_index = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3}
    counts = [0 for _ in letters_index]
    size = len(counts)

    res = []
    last_index = 0
    for letter in test_2:
        for index in count(last_index):
            counts[index%size] += 1
            if index % size == letters_index[letter]:
                res.append(counts[index%size])
                last_index = index + 1
                break
    return res
```

Comment: Yes - I completely forgot you can actually say 'a' < 'b' in python...

Comment: @ChristinaZhou yeah that really simplifies things :D Well here you got yourself a complicated working solution for reference :)